# Python: Parsing numeric values from string using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing python code to parse different types of numbers from a string using regular expressions and have run into an annoying problem which I don't understand.

My code is as follows:

```
import re    

test_string = "Distributions $54.00 bob $26 and 0.30 5% ($0.23) 2,333,450"

num_values = re.findall(r"\(?\$?[0-9]+.?[0-9]*%?\)?|[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*", test_string)
```

The output is:

```
['$54.00', '0.30', '5%', '($0.23)', '2,333', '450']
```

So the code is working great for everything but the '2,333,450' string which for some reason gets cut into two elements.

The annoying thing is that when I reverse the order of the regular expression:

```
num_values = re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*|\(?\$?[0-9]+.?[0-9]*%?\)?", test_string)
```

I get this output:

```
['$54.00', '$26 ', '0', '30', '5', '($0.23)', '2,333,450']
```

So my '2,333,450' string comes out fine but then I can't properly parse numbers with % symbols or decimal points (unless it is in brackets).

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I suspect that the period in the first part of the regex should be escaped with a leading backslash (if it is intended to match a decimal point), currently it matches any character which is why you have a match containing a space `'$26 '`.

The `2,333` is therefore matched to the first part of your regex (the `,` matches with the unescaped `.`), which is why it didn't match the `,450` part of that number.

Whilst your (corrected) regex works with your limited sample data which might be good enough, it may be too broad for general use - for instance it matches `($1267.3%`. You could build up a bigger regex out of smaller parts, however this can get ugly fast:

```
import re

test_string = "Distributions $54.00 bob $26 and 0.30 5% ($0.23) 2,333,450"
test_string += " $12,354.00 43 43.12 1234,12 ($123,456.78"

COMMA_SEP_NUMBER = r'\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*' # require groups of 3
DECIMAL_NUMBER = r'\d+(?:\.\d*)?'
COMMA_SEP_DECIMAL = COMMA_SEP_NUMBER + r'(?:\.(?:\d{3},)*\d{0,3})?' # are commas used after the decimal point?

regex_items = []

regex_items.append('\$' + COMMA_SEP_DECIMAL)
regex_items.append('\$' + DECIMAL_NUMBER)
regex_items.append(COMMA_SEP_DECIMAL + '\%')
regex_items.append(DECIMAL_NUMBER + '\%')
regex_items.append(COMMA_SEP_DECIMAL)
regex_items.append(DECIMAL_NUMBER)

r = re.compile('|'.join(regex_items))

print r.findall(test_string)
```

Note that this doesn't account for parenthesis around the numbers, and it fails on `1234,12` (which should probably be interpreted as two numbers `1234` and `12`) due to matching `123` against the COMMA_SEP_NUMBER pattern.

This is a problem with this technique because if the DECIMAL_NUMBER pattern comes first, COMMA_SEP_NUMBER will never be matched.

Finally, here's a nice tool for visualising regex

```
\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.(?:\d{3},)*\d{0,3})?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SAH_r9_Vq21tv7V1)

Answer (score 1):

How about merge two parts into one?

```
>>> test_string = "Distributions $54.00 bob $26 and 0.30 5% ($0.23) 2,333,450"
>>> re.findall(r'\(?\$?\d+(?:,\d+)*\.?\d*%?\)?', test_string)
['$54.00', '$26', '0.30', '5%', '($0.23)', '2,333,450']
```

- Replaced `.` with `\.` to match dot literally instead of matching any charcter.
- Replaced `[0-9]` with `\d`. (`\d` matches digit)